# Building a LAN emulator for gaming purposes

Tags: networking, lan, upnp, portforwarding, game-development

I built a simple utility for Warcraft III that allows users to join remotely hosted games just as if they were accessible in their LAN. Its idea is pretty straightforward:

1. Players A and B want to play. They set up port forwarding on their routers, launch my utility and exchange their external IP addresses.
2. Players then enter each others' IP addresses in my utility and one of the players creates a Warcraft III game.
3. My utility uses the Warcraft III packet format to query its local machine for any hosted Warcraft III games. If it receives a response (with game information), it simply forwards it to every IP on the list.
4. Due to port forwarding, the packet (datagram, to be more specific) reaches the other Warcraft III instance and so the other user is now able to see his friend's game, as well as join it.

It works very well. However, it still requires users to set port forwarding and here's my question - what would be the best approach to avoid it?

I've been thinking about UPnP / NAT-PMP but that's mostly useful when it is **my** application that is listening. In this case, I only notify Warcraft III on the other end that there's a game on my machine. But can I create a port mapping for another application?

I'm surely missing something out, so I'd be glad if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Off topic for SO, better question for Super User or Server Fault